# How to customize the full text search?

Tags: database, search, full-text-search, customization

Full text search is becoming a tedious job using the relational databases’ approach. Can  anybody suggest an   alternate option if any or way to customize the full text search ?

Comment: Can you explain the question little bit clear .

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you can use lucene for your search and have the "id" for the lucene record point to the relational data you want to use.

Answer (score 0):

Well,  it cannot be stated  exactly as an alternative but full text search engines are better in case of quickly searching high volumes of unstructured text on the contrary to relational databases which excel at storing & manipulating structured data. So, It actually depends on your search suitability.

Answer (score 0):

I think if the high volume of  unstructured  text is searched with ease it is there by making the search process more convenient and user friendly. I guess it makes the full text search engines an obvious  choice in that case. I have tried Solr and found it quite efficient. You can check out: http://search.lucidimagination.com/search/document/CDRG_ch06_6.1